# loading a UDF's statements into a string variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

We have a stored procedure that uses UDFs. We need to modify the content of these UDFs on the fly. Yeah, I know, I know... Not my choice. This is exactly what we are tying to do:

1. Read the contents of a UDF
2. Modify the contents and create a new UDF
3. Use the UDF in an `executesql` statement

Is there a way to get the contents of a udf into a varchar (or nvarchar) that I can then modify using string functions?

Comment: Not to rub it in, but this just sounds painful

Comment: `SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules where object_id=object_id('foo.bar')`. This sounds a horrible idea for lots of reasons though. Can I ask why you have this requirement?

Comment: Ugh! I feel your pain. Make sure you test your final solution using race conditions, you need to know some other process isn't going to mysteriously change your UDF before you are done the first process. Like @Martin, I am curious to know why this is requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select object_definition(object_id('UDFName'))
```

> Is there a way to get the contents of
>   a udf into a varchar (or nvarchar)
>   that I can then modify using string
>   functions?

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) 

-- get function definition to @str
select @str = object_definition(object_id('UDFName'))

-- Modify definition
set @str = replace(@str, 'CREATE FUNCTION', 'ALTER FUNCTION')

-- execute alter function
exec (@str)
```